# Opening Browser in Android

Tags: android

I tried to open link in a browser in JavaScriptInterface but it seems it didn't work. What the problem with the code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class JavaScriptInterface extends Activity{

    Context mContext;
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void openLink(){

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

    }

}
```

I already have the required permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: This should work; are you sure, `openLink` is being called? You should log its execution into logcat to make sure. Also, are there any errors? Btw. note that you do not need the internet permission to send an intent to open an URL. You only need that permission if your application itself wants to access the network directly.

Comment: yes, openLink was called since having `Toast.makeText(mContext, "some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` work.

Comment: im new to this. `JavaScriptInterface` is not defined as activity. This is just called with javascript inside WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you extending an `Activity`. Though you are initializing `mContext` in the constructor, it will never be used for `startActivity()`.

You may want to code like:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void openLink(){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    }
}
```

(not extending an Activity, and calling `startActivity()` in `mContext`)

BTW, you don't need the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` to invoke this intent. You need it for a `WebView`, may be.